# How can I test a signature violation without calling a perl function?

Tags: perl, signature, subroutine, arity

Let's say I have,

```
use experimental 'signatures';
sub foo ($bar) { return 0 };
```

Now if I call it without the right [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity), I'll get an error.

```
# Too few arguments for subroutine 'main::foo'
foo()
# Too many arguments for subroutine 'main::foo'
foo(1,2);
```

However, how can I test that. Let's say I want to make sure that someone implements a `package Bar` such that its function `foo` requires one argument. Is there a way to do this without running that code.

---

I see this question as different from [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63836449/124486) because even if I can't read the signature through some kind of Perl API, there may be a way to test that a subroutine is declared with a specific signature? An answer to that question can be used to answer this one. But an answer to this question may not answer that one.

Comment: Perhaps a better question is, why should you want to test that a subroutine is used correctly? Most Perl code can be misused, it takes a knowledgeable user to write Per code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From irc.freenode.net/#perl,

> 15:06 < Grinnz> EvanCarroll: yes, there's no way to do that [either](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63836449/124486)

He's speaking in reference to an earlier question about [getting the signature of a function with an API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63836449/124486).

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is try to call it in a string-eval:

```
$ perl -E 'sub foo ($bar) { return $bar } eval "foo()"; print "error: $@"'
error: Not enough arguments for main::foo at (eval 1) line 1, near "()
"
```

It needs to be a *string*-eval, not a block-eval, as you need to catch a compile-time error.